# Postrgesql running on coreos

Tags: postgresql, docker, coreos

I am running a postgresql 9.4 container on CoreOS and something keeps consuming the drive space.  I originally thought it might be an issue with copy on write that was causing the disk to fill up so I ran chatter +C on the data directory that postgres is using.   Is there something I am missing that is causing a relatively inactive database to consume 75% of the hard drive space?  Has anyone else had issues with postgres running in a docker container in CoreOS?

Comment: I found this page that might be the answer to the issues I have been having.  
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=CoreOS-Btrfs-To-EXT4-OverlayFS

Comment: I switched to the Alpha Channel which had EXT4 and have not run into the same issue.